# Google sheets split multi-line cell into new rows (+ duplicate surrounding row entries)

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-sheets-arrays

I'm compiling a database of business address info, including key staff for each business. The Google spreadsheet I've inherited for this project includes a column for 'key staff' (in column B), with multiple key staff names listed in the same cell, separated by line breaks (ie CHAR(10) ).
There is one business per row. The number of lines in the 'key staff' cell varies row-by-row. 
My initial sheet looks like this:

[image]

I need to do the following to optimize this sheet:

1. split each multi-line ‘key staff’ cell so each key staff name appears on its own row. This requires that new row/s be inserted beneath the original row.
2. duplicate the data from all other cells on the original row (i.e. from columns A & C:E), so that each new row contains the full data for each business
3. I need an **automated** process - I'll have about 1000 businesses to process so can't do this with any manual steps

The sheet should then look like this:

[image]

Using `=TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(B1,CHAR(10)))` obviously only goes part of the way - it doesn’t insert new rows and doesn’t duplicate the surrounding column entries. All help gratefully accepted!

Comment: Related: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/88517/split-a-column-of-strings-with-a-single-formula-returning-an-array

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use a custom function.

### Code

```
function result(range) {
  var splitCol = 1; // split on column B
  var output2 = [];
  for(var i=0, iLen=range.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    var s = range[i][splitCol].split("\n");    
    for(var j=0, jLen=s.length; j<jLen; j++) {
      var output1 = []; 
      for(var k=0, kLen=range[0].length; k<kLen; k++) {
        if(k == splitCol) {
          output1.push(s[j]);
        } else {
          output1.push(range[i][k]);
        }
      }
      output2.push(output1);
    }    
  }
  return output2;
}
```

### Explanation

The script evaluates each row, and particularly the second column of each row (in JavaScript arrays are zero based, so column 2 corresponds to index 1 of the array). It splits the contents of that cell, into multiple values and uses the `"\n"` as delimiter (line feed). After that it adds the existing info to an array and only add the individual results, when it hits index 1 (`k == 1)`. The newly prepared row is then added to another array, that's being returned to show the result.

### Screenshot

*data*
[image]

*result*
[image]

### Example

I've created an example file for you: **[multi-line cells into new rows](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LeZN0Q4rHl68LmYV3yA4ErFJDggXFwMRoQmFpJmepJY/edit?usp=sharing)**.

- Add the script under *Tools > Script editor*.
- Save the script, the name doesn't matter.
- Use the custom function in a cell just like a built in (see the screenshot above).

Comment: Awesome awesome awesome - buy this man a beer! Many thanks Jacob, that's exactly what I need.

Comment: And how to define the range? ( get this message "cannot read property "length" from undefined" Thanks!

Comment: on a really large file, this will likely fail...result too large.

Comment: Brilliantly answered, just one bug. FIRST COLUMN in given range should NOT have the DELIMITER. Temporary workaround is to have serial numbes or static value as first column. Not tried but first  blank column  should also solve the problem.

Comment: Was hopeful this would work. I have a similar Sheet, but it has about 300 rows currently. Your script just outputs "Loading...". With an error of "Error: Loading data...". The Apps Script is saying `TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`

Comment: For me this worked but the terminology has changed and the function should be put at location: Extensions -> AppScripts

Answer (score 6):

A repeatable solution will need a script.

But for a one-time effort, you could just use    `=SPLIT(B3,CHAR(10))`.
This will give you all the person's names in side-by-side helper columns, like this:

[image]

Copy / Paste-special, values    the helper-column contents.

And for each helper column that is used   (hopefully not too many, 'cos hopefully you don't have too many people in any one business) manually copy-and-paste the block of rows to the end of the current block.  (That's not a great description, but you get the drift.)

Comment: Hi Mary, thanks but I need the individ. person names dropped into new ROWS, (with extra rows auto-generated to accommodate them), then the surrounding info copied beside the new 'person' cells. And I need a 100% automated process - I can't do this manually for a thousand-or-so businesses!

Comment: You don't need to do the manual step for the whole thousand businesses.   You only need to do it for the maximum number of pepole associated with any one of those businesses:   eg if one business has six people, then there will be six new helper columns created, so you have to to a manual copy-and-paste six times, one for each column.

Comment: Someone could write a script for this (I'm not that someone!) - but really the time spent testing it would probably be greater than the time spend doing it manually.

Answer (score 4):

For folks who might not immediately grasp how to use the helpful **custom function** in the [accepted answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/62476/88163):

- You need more than one sheet, in the example the two sheets are `DATA` and `RESULT`. The `RESULT` sheet is empty until the query has been run. You can see the query which refers to the `DATA` sheet in Jacob's screenshot.
- You will most likely need to modify the comparison value for `k` on line 8 which refers to the column where your data to parse should be found. The same number will need to go into the 2nd array value on line 4.
- You may need to modify the delimiter on line 4 which is currently `\n`

To make all this a teeny bit easier, I took the same code and extracted the **delimiter** and **target column** into variables set at the top of the function. As Jacob mentions target **column count starts with 0** as the first number.

```
function result(range) {
  delimiter = ", "
  targetColumn = 10

  var output2 = [];
  for(var i=0, iLen=range.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    var s = range[i][targetColumn].split(delimiter);    
    for(var j=0, jLen=s.length; j<jLen; j++) {
      var output1 = []; 
      for(var k=0, kLen=range[0].length; k<kLen; k++) {
        if(k == targetColumn) {
          output1.push(s[j]);
        } else {
          output1.push(range[i][k]);
        }
      }
      output2.push(output1);
    }    
  }
  return output2;
}
```

References

- [Custom Functions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)

Comment: If I run the code, it says: TypeError: Cannot read property "length" from undefined. thank you so much. Answer should be here: Answer must be somewhere here (developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/…) But I keep having the same error.

Comment: @user2060451 The solution on this answer shows the code of custom function, it's not intended to be ran from the script editor. I added a link to the custom function guide from Google.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation Ruben. It helped a lot :)