# Splitting multiple multi-line cells into new rows

Tags: google-sheets

I am working on employee data and the data I  have received comes with two cells (Proj Name and Count of Hours) which have multiple names/ hours in the same cell separated by line breaks.

I have looked through the solution presented in this link [Google sheets split multi-line cell into new rows (+ duplicate surrounding row entries)](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/60861/google-sheets-split-multi-line-cell-into-new-rows-duplicate-surrounding-row-e?rq=1) but it only appears to work when there is one column with multi-line unlike mine which has more than one which needs to be split.

[image: Problem Description]

Comment: I think that no makes sense to repeat the content of the column "Sum hours" as it looks to be to hold aggregated data (the sum of values of the column "Count hours" for the related employee). Just delete that column and use the code of the referred Q&A. By the way it's possible to split multiline cells without scripts.