# Split contents of comma separated cell and send to new row(s) with adjacent cell values

Tags: google-sheets

*Question is unique from Google sheets split multi-line cell into new rows (+ duplicate surrounding row entries) in that the parse is required in three separate columns rather than just one.

I have a google sheet that accepts order data from my online store. If the order contains one single product sale, the output looks like:

```
    Date | Order Number | Order Name | Item | Quantity | Price
```

If the order contains 2 product sales, the output looks like:

```
    Date | Order Number | Order Name | Item, Item | Quantity, Quantity | Price, Price
```

If the order contains 3 product sales, the output looks like:

```
    Date | Order Number | Order Name | Item, Item, Item | Quantity, Quantity, Quantity | Price, Price, Price
```

And so on...

Is it possible to separate the comma deliminated contents of the cells, transpose and maintain the adjacent data like so:

```
    Date | Order Number | Order Name | Item | Quantity | Price
    Date | Order Number | Order Name | Item | Quantity | Price
    Date | Order Number | Order Name | Item | Quantity | Price
```

For example...

```
    9/15/16 | 1004 | Jim Johnson | Beer, Wine | 2, 5 | 20, 100
```

Would give...

```
    9/15/16 | 1004 | Jim Johnson | Beer | 2 | 20
    9/15/16 | 1004 | Jim Johnson | Wine | 5 | 100
```

Question is unique from [Google sheets split multi-line cell into new rows (+ duplicate surrounding row entries)](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/60861/google-sheets-split-multi-line-cell-into-new-rows-duplicate-surrounding-row-e) in that the parse is required in three separate columns rather than just one.

Comment: Hey @Rubén thank you for linking to that post. It definitely gets me closer to where I need to be but I'm failing to get that results I need. My question is unique to that post in that the parsing is required in three separate columns.

Comment: Consider to try to apply the suggested solutions three times, one for each separated columns.

Comment: I extended the description of the formula on [this answer](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/98535/88163). I think that this could be helpful to find the solution for this question.