# Split comma separated cell data into rows while keeping surrounding row data

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I'm trying to accomplish the below input and output in Google Sheets.

[image: Valid XHTML]

I was actually able to find a [partial solution on Stack Exchange.](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/87190/154790)

This is the script I pulled, but it only functions on one column, whereas I need to function on two at the same time:

```
function result(range) {
  delimiter = ", "
  targetColumn = 1

  var output2 = [];
  for(var i=0, iLen=range.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    var s = range[i][targetColumn].split(delimiter);    
    for(var j=0, jLen=s.length; j<jLen; j++) {
      var output1 = []; 
      for(var k=0, kLen=range[0].length; k<kLen; k++) {
        if(k == targetColumn) {
          output1.push(s[j]);
        } else {
          output1.push(range[i][k]);
        }
      }
      output2.push(output1);
    }    
  }
  return output2;
}
```

Comment: Well, that wasn't adapting his code, the 'targetColumn' just allows you to select which column you want to split, which in my case is B (or 1) and C (or 2), but the code only allows me to set one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this will work for you:

```
function myFunction(range) {
    delimiter = ", ";
    targetColumn = 1;
    targetColumn2 = 2;

    var output2 = [];
    for(var i=0, iLen=range.length; i<iLen; i++) {
        var s = range[i][targetColumn].split(delimiter);    
        var s2 = range[i][targetColumn2].split(delimiter);
        for(var j=0, jLen=s.length; j<jLen; j++) {
           var output1 = []; 
           for(var k=0, kLen=range[0].length; k<kLen; k++) {
           if(k == targetColumn) {
              output1.push(s[j]);
           } 
           else if (k == targetColumn2) {
               output1.push(s2[j]);
           } else {
                output1.push(range[i][k]);
           }
        }
        output2.push(output1);
      } 
     }
    return output2;
  }
```

The other option would be to more or less run your own function twice. Create another copy of it, this time setting targetColumn = 2. Run the first function on the cells you have, and then run the second function on what the first function returns.