# Google Sheets split by " ," & add new rows

Tags: google-sheets

This is an example:

[image]
I need to split by "  , " in a new row and duplicate the others
The desired output on a new sheet:

[image]

Comment: Related: [Split comma separated cell data into rows while keeping surrounding row data](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/106027/88163), [Google sheets split multi-line cell into new rows (+ duplicate surrounding row entries)](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/60861/88163)

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do it for one row

```
={transpose(split(rept(A2&",",counta(split(B2,","))),",")),transpose(split(B2,",")),transpose(split(C2,","))}
```