# Split multi-line (comma-separated) cell into new rows + duplicate surrounding row entries

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, formulas, google-sheets-custom-function

Based on: [Google sheets split multi-line cell into new rows (+ duplicate surrounding row entries)](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/60861/google-sheets-split-multi-line-cell-into-new-rows-duplicate-surrounding-row-e/123868?noredirect=1#comment111784_123868)

How can I rewrite this for use of a comma as separator **and** remove blank spaces?

Input sheet:

```
Row 1: Albert A. Anderson, Beatrice B. Bargel ->
```

The desired output on a new sheet:

```
Row 1: Albert A. Anderson  (plus surrounding cells)  
Row 2: Beatrice B. Bargel  (plus surrounding cells)
```

[Example spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YtKhZ5C3KFEl18-d6_FAYuA8XXFQejcsIGtKudibdbo/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### SCRIPT :

```
function transform(range) {
  var output2 = [];
  for(var i=0, iLen=range.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    var s = range[i][1].split(", ");    
    for(var j=0, jLen=s.length; j<jLen; j++) {
      var output1 = []; 
      for(var k=0, kLen=range[0].length; k<kLen; k++) {
        if(k == 1) {
          output1.push(s[j]);
        } else {
          output1.push(range[i][k]);
        }
      }
      output2.push(output1);
    }    
  }
  return output2;
}
```

#### FORMULA :

```
=TRANSFORM(A1:E4)
```

#### RESULT :

[image: 4]

Comment: Super cool. Thank you. This is exactly what I needed. You just made life easier for all my students :-)

Comment: Where in Your formular does it say "column b" if I ever want to change that?

Comment: ... and how does the formular know how many columns there is? If I ever decided to put extra columns in the sheets.

Comment: If You don't mind... Can You take another look at the example? I have tried to tweak your formular and it seems to work as intended except that it squeezes out a column (B).

Comment: @AllanBech squeezes? what does it mean?

Comment: If you take another look at the example You will see, that column B is missing from the range (A1:N).

Comment: The problem is that when the formula is splitting the names in column C it replaces(/deletes) twith column B in Solution-sheet.